# Webpack why only scss works, but css does not?

Tags: webpack

When I write in the vue js component (), then everything works, but if I remove the lang = "scss"> caption, normal css stops working and the following error appears:

> ModuleBuildError in
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) File was
> processed with these loaders:  *
> ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js  *
> ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js You may need an additional
> loader to handle the result of these loaders.
>
> > .btn-warning { |   background-color: #FF8800; | }

What could be the problem?

My web pack settings:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var WriteFilePlugin =  require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new BundleTracker({
      path: __dirname,
      filename: './assets/webpack-stats.json',
    }),
    new WriteFilePlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'style-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader',
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
          esModule: false,
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: I think you should add `'css-loader'` in the `use` array of `test: /\.css$/`

Comment: added this did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `sass-loader` with `css-loader` in this ruler:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [
     'vue-style-loader',
     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
     'style-loader',
     'css-loader', //  <--- Here. Instead of sass-loader
   ],
},
```

`sass-loader` works on *.scss files. `css-loader` works on *.css files.

`sass-loader` needs `css-loader` as a follow-through loader (or other loader that handles .css files)